# UNIX—ASCII files appear to be binary

Tags: unix, mercurial, ascii, binaryfiles

I've just tried to `hg diff` some C source files and was told that they are binary.

So, my question is: How can I convince UNIX and Mercurial that these files are, in fact, ASCII?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

hg thinks the files are binary because they have embedded nulls (ASCII 0).

EDIT: You can start with simple script:

```
for i in *.c
do
temp=$(mktemp);
tr -d '\000' < "$i" > $temp
mv -f $temp "$i"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew.

Any thoughts on how to find/remove these pesky nulls?

Comment: use `cat -A` and look for `^@`